# How to avoid data disappearing from graph when click on the legend - React ECharts

Tags: reactjs, graph, legend, echarts, legend-properties

I am trying to avoid the default click behavior on the legend of **React ECharts**.

When the user click on any legend item, the corresponding plotted data disappear
from the graph until the user click on the legend again to show up.

How can I avoid this default behavior so that **when clicking on any legend item, nothing happens**?

I already tried what is described here but didn't work:

[ECharts: Disable default click action on legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324699/echarts-disable-default-click-action-on-legends)

Here is part of the code:

```
legend: {
  itemGap: 15,
  left: '0',
  selectedMode: 'none', // or 'onlyHover'
  ...
}
```

None of the options for **selectedMode** above worked.

EChart versions on the project:

```
"echarts": "^5.4.1",
"echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
```

Could anyone help ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

the **selectedMode** property should take a boolean as the value
for the version I am using.

```
legend: {
  selectedMode: false, // default is true
  ...
}
```

It is also here in the documentation:

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.selectedMode